# Is it more efficient to query a view from a stored procedure or include the table join in the stored procedure?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sql-view, sql-function

I have a database structure in MySQL similar to Instagram, where I have a table containing paths to pictures in a file system and a table containing user information as such:

Users:

```
ID | userName  | age | gender
---|-----------|-----|-------
 1 | MrBanana  | 15  |   0   
 2 | BobTheMan | 21  |   0   
 3 |  TheBest  | 19  |   1
 4 |   MsTest  | 24  |   1
```

Pictures:

```
ID |   Path    | userID 
---|-----------|--------
 1 | www.test1 |    2    
 2 | www.test2 |    4       
 3 | www.test3 |    3    
 4 | www.test4 |    2
```

Now the requirement is that whenever a picture is called up it will include the userName and ID. So the first Idea I had was to create a view that joins the two table so that a picture now also has the user name and ID of the images attached to it and then query the pictures out of that view. The query would be placed in a stored procedure. Now my question is if this is efficient or if it where more efficient to do the query and join in one stamens and put that into the stored procedure ?

My concern is that if I use the view approach, every time it queries the view it will have to first join the entirety of the two tables and if these tables become very big this would be a very time consuming process. So if I create a stored procedure that first finds all the needed pictures and then joins the user to it it would be more efficient.

I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly and would like to ask for help on which approach is better and would scale more effectively ?

Comment: You are likely to get better answers if you specify what rdms you are using.   I think I have seen somewhere that MsSQL optimiser will check the source query for the view and only pull the information it needs.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why would you access the view through a stored procedure?  Access the view through a query.

Comment: I am using `MySQL` and the reason I am using a stored procedure is to limit access to the data as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which RDBMS are you using, but from my experience with SQL Server (and I guess that the other vendors do the same) an ordinary view would use the indexes
of the tables included in the view query as if you where doing that query outside the view.

So if you are worrying about if your vwPicturesWithUser would use the index of Pictures table when you query for the picture with ID=3, the answer is yes (well I guess that somebody could come up with some odd scenario where the query planner decides to ignore the index, but that would happen too querying without the view).